# AWS Usage plan API Keys and Custom authorizer

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda-authorizer

Are usage plans keys in AWS API Gateway evaluated ahead of Custom Authorizers ?
I can see the flaw of custom authorizers of being able to flooded externally thus cutting off normal usage if there is no way for Usage Plan API keys to be evaluated before Authorizers are run.

Comment: please be more detailed how are these api keys introduced in api gateway through headers from client or through your lambda function